# Настройка платежной системы в мобильном приложении, фреймворк Flutter

Tags: flutter, mobile-development, apple, платежи, google-pay

Всем привет!
Прошу кого-нибудь объяснить, как произвести интеграцию платежной системы в мобильное приложение на фреймворке Flutter. Само приложение уже написано, так же есть REST API сервер.
Нужно сделать интеграцию Google Pay/Apple pay.

Как я понимаю, нужно сначала сделать платежный шлюз, например в Сбербанке, потом его использовать в подключаемой платежной системе?

Просто хотелось бы понять весь пайплайн работы над интеграцией платежной системы в мобильное приложение.

Буду очень благодарен за любую помощь. Спасибо заранее.

Answer (score 1):

Да все правильно, сначала нужно подключить платежный шлюз (интернет эквайринг). Общение с шлюзом можно делать как из приложения, так из вашего сервер (но нужно соответствовать сертификации). Например для [Tinkoff](https://github.com/MadBrains/Tinkoff-Acquiring-SDK-Flutter) уже есть SDK на dart.

Потом нужно добавить Google Pay/Apple pay в приложение, есть уже готовые плагины, один из них [Mad Pay](https://github.com/MadBrains/Mad-Pay-Flutter). Чтобы он работал его нужно настроить, получить MerchantId из [Google](https://developers.google.com/pay/api#participating-processors) и [Apple](https://help.apple.com/developer-account/#/devb2e62b839?sub=dev103e030bb).

Далее когда мы все подключим, нам нужно будет передавать из Google Pay/Apple pay токен платежа в платежный шлюз, и обрабатывать сам платеж...

---

Полезные ссылки: [Приема платежей в мобильном приложении на Flutter](https://habr.com/ru/company/tinkoff/blog/544080/), [Как сделать оплату и покупки в Mad Pay с Apple Pay | Google Pay|Tinkoff Acquiring](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4AmZShGjlc4)

Comment: Спасибо большое!